# Proximal operator of squared Euclidean distance to a set, i.e., $\operatorname{dist}\left(\right)$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Could anyone please help me to prove that a proximal operator of squared Euclidean distance to a set $\mathcal{C}$ is

> $$\operatorname{prox}_{t\operatorname{dist}^2}\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{(t+1)} \left( x + t \operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x \right) \right)$$ cf. slide#6.21 in [[1]](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf)?

The squared distance function is (with $1/2$ scaling):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{dist}^2\left(x\right) 
&= \frac{1}{2}\inf_{y \in \mathcal{C}} \| x - y \|^2  \equiv \frac{1}{2}\|x -  \operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x \right) \|_2^2.
\end{align}

---

Attempt:

> Definition: The proximal mapping of closed convex function $f$ is
> $$\operatorname{prox}_f\left(x\right) = \arg\min_{z} f(z) + \frac{1}{2t} \| z - x\|_2^2 $$

Let $f(z) := \operatorname{dist}^2\left(z\right) = \frac{1}{2}\|z -  \operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( z \right) \|_2^2$.

To this end, we can plugin the definition of the considered function to the proximal mapping such that
\begin{align}
&0 = \nabla f(z) + \frac{1}{t}\left(z - x\right) 
\end{align}

Now, I am unsure about the gradient of squared distance function unless I assume that $\operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x \right) \leftarrow\operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( z \right) $, then $\operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x\right)$ will be seen as a constant and straightfoward to compute the gradient of $f(z)$, i.e., the gradient is
$\nabla f(z) = z -  \operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x \right)$, otherwise I don't think it is possible to find the gradient in general, correct? Then, we can find the proximal operator
$$z = \frac{1}{(t+1)}\left(x + t\operatorname{proj}_{\mathcal{C}}\left( x \right) \right)$$

I think the problem in my understanding is the gradient of such a squared distance to a set. I will raised another question instead for the clarity.

Comment: The gradient of the squared distance function is in fact given by the identity minus projection ($\nabla f(z) = z - \operatorname{proj}_C(z)$. This can be looked up. In order to have the same solution you should note that the definition of the proximal operator is usually written with a parameter, i.e. $\operatorname{prox}_{t f}(x) = \arg\min_u\{f(u) + \frac{1}{2 t}|| u-x||^2\}$.

Comment: However, if I remember correctly there should be a way to solve this problem by pure algebra (manipulating the squares inside the argmin and noting that the proximal operator of the 2 norm squared is given by $\operatorname{prox}_{t ||\cdot||^2}(x) = \frac{1}{1+t}x$, which looks very similar to the desired form of your prox.

Comment: @xel Thank you. Yes, I missed that $t$. So, I can match my derivations, but I am not sure whether my understanding of the gradient of a distance function is correct. I am not aware of any good reference where they have proved the gradient of a distance function. Are you ware of it? Thank you in advance

Comment: for example:
Bauschke, Heinz H., and Patrick L. Combettes. Convex analysis and monotone operator theory in Hilbert spaces. Vol. 408. New York: Springer, 2011.
Corollary 12.30. 
But as I mentioned, there is most likely also an elementary way to show it (which I assume is the way to go if this some kind of homework/exercise.

Comment: @xel Thank you for the pointer. I really appreciate it.